# replacing fixed amount of text in a large file

Tags: linux, unix, sed, large-files, file-manipulation

I'm trying to replace a small amount of text on a specific line of a large log file (totaling ~40 mil lines):

```
sed -i '20000000s/.\{5\}$/zzzzz/' log_file
```

The purpose of this is to "mark" a line with an expected unique string, for later testing.

The above command works fine, but in-place editing of `sed` (and `perl`) creates a temp file, which is costly.

Is there a way to replace a fixed number of characters (i.e. 5 chars with 5 other chars) in a file without having to create a temp file, or a very large buffer, which would wind up becoming a temp file itself.

Comment: just split the log file (by day, week, month, year, decade, century, severity, task or whatever)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `dd` to replace some bytes in place:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=path/to/file bs=1 count=10 conv=notrunc skip=1000
```

would write 10 zeros (0x00) after the 1000s byte. You can put whatever you want to replace inside a file and write the path to it in the `if` parameter. Then you had to insert the size of the replacement file into the `count` parameter, so the whole file gets read.

the `conv=notrunc` parameter tells `dd` to leave the end of the file untruncated.

This should work well for any 1-byte file encoding.

Comment: thanks, I didn't think of using `dd` for this. But this method works by setting the number of bytes to skip, not lines.

Comment: You can calculate the byte offset with `head` and `wc` (and some arithmetic)

Answer (score 0):

[`ex`](http://man.cx/ex) is a scriptable file editor, so it will work in-place:

```
ex log_file << 'END_OF_COMMANDS'
20000000s/.\{5\}$/zzzzz/
w
q
END_OF_COMMANDS
```

Comment: most editors don't work in place: It would mean that you didn't have to save anything, because everything you write would be inside the file you're editing. ex neither.